# write a function or method to collect messages within a time interval

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function call() that is triggered multiple times , I want to collect all the messages for 5 seconds and then flush / start over again for the next set

```py
def on_collect(data):
    print(data)
    
_list=[]
def call(data):
    global _list
    # keep collecting for 5 seconds
    _list.append(data)
    on_collect(_list)
   
call('a')
call('b')
# after 1 sec
call('c')
```

I want to collect all the output as `['a','b','c']`.
How  would I achieve this in python

Comment: You can use the `time` module to delay (or continue) for (n) seconds, if you like.  Hint: look up `sleep`, and `while`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you want the the code to wait for a specific time period (say 1 second as per your question). Then the easiest way would be to use the sleep function from the time library.

```
from time import sleep


def on_collect(data):
    print(data)

_list=[]
def call(data):
        global _list
        sleep(5) # Sleep for 5 seconds
        _list.append(data)
        on_collect(_list)



call('a')
call('b')
sleep(1) #Sleep for 1 second
call('c')
```

If you want the function to run again, then you could use a loop.
Also I do not see any reason you might want to wait for 5 seconds or 1 second in this code snippet, but if you are getting this info from a remote server, then you should be using async function.

Comment: True.  However, this does not address OP’s question regarding ‘keep collecting for 5 seconds’.

Comment: Thanks for your answers , however both of them is giving as [a] .... [a][b]  ... [a][b][c] But I need it in one shot as [a, b, c] .. . Vyom , I think I will try your idea of async function . I am new to python so reading it up , but I try that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the time difference since the last call using the time module.

```
import time


def on_collect(data):
    print(data)

last_call=time.time()
_list=[]
def call(data):
        global _list
        if time.time() - last_call > 5*60:
          _list=[]
        _list.append(data)
        on_collect(_list)



call('a')
call('b')
sleep(1) #Sleep for 1 second
call('c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment and understanding your question better, here is the code. The output is in the format as you said, `['a','b','c']`

```
from time import time, sleep


def on_collect(data):
    print(data)


_list = []


def call(data):
    global _list
    _list.append(data)
    if len(_list) % 3 == 0:
        on_collect(_list)


temp_time = time()
while (time() - temp_time) < 5:
    call('a')
    sleep(1)
    call('b')
    sleep(1)
    call('c')
    sleep(1)
```